# how to use formatting to write a new csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am using

```
csvFile=open("yelloUSA.csv",'w+')
```

to make a new csv file.
now I want to write the file names from 1-10. But I want to use formatting to write the names. how can I do that?
I used below code but it is showing error

```
for i in range(0,10):
    csvFile=open("{0}.csv",'w+').format(i)
    writer=csv.writer(csvFile)
```

Comment: `csvFile=open("{0}.csv",'w+').format(i)` should be `csvFile=open("{0}.csv".format(i),'w+')`

Answer (score 1):

The `format` is a method of a `string` object. You are applying it to the result of `open` function, which if a `file` object. You need to apply it to the filename string

```
filename = "{0}.csv".format(i)
csvFile=open(filename ,'w+')
```